# JQuery: fire action when element is in view

Tags: jquery, events, dom, visible

In the footer of my site I'm using counUp.js (Link: http://inorganik.github.io/countUp.js/ ) to count up three numbers. I added this code at the bottom of the site:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
          var c1 = new countUp("upnum1", 1, 27, 0, 4);
          var c2 = new countUp("upnum2", 1, 10, 0, 4);
          var c3 = new countUp("upnum3", 1, 27, 0, 4);
          var c4 = new countUp("upnum4", 1, 1000, 0, 4);
          window.onload = function() {
            c1.start();
            c2.start();
            c3.start();
            c4.start();
          }
    </script>
```

This works well, but starts counting once the page is loaded of course. How do I manage to fire this effect when the containing div of the numbers is 'in view' and not when the page is loaded? Tried several jQuery things but can't find a working solution... Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a simple check to see whether or not an element is in the viewport.

You can choose either to use a plugin or pure JQuery.

### Relevant HTML :

```
<div id="inViewport">Is this in the viewport?</div>
```

### Pure JQuery :

Here is the fiddle for this :
http://jsfiddle.net/zWtkc/1/

```
$.fn.isOnScreen = function(){

    var win = $(window);

    var viewport = {
        top : win.scrollTop(),
        left : win.scrollLeft()
    };
    viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
    viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();

    var bounds = this.offset();
    bounds.right = bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
    bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();

    return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));

};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($('#inViewport').isOnScreen()) {
            // The element is visible, do something
            alert("in viewport!");
        } else {
            // The element is NOT visible, do something else
        }
    });
});
```

### Plugins :

You can use this plugin : https://github.com/teamdf/jquery-visible/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('#inViewport').visible(true)) {
        // The element is visible, do something
    } else {
        // The element is NOT visible, do something else
    }
});
```

Or you can use this plugin : http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport which allows for viewport selectors and your code will look like this :

```
$('#inViewport:in-viewport').doSomething();
```

Comment: Yeah but if I get this right this checks if the element is visible on pageload, not when scrolled down to it.

Comment: I need something like: after scroll, check if #div is visible, if so do: countUp, if not, do nothing.

Comment: @MarcL updated my answer with pure JQuery. The `$(document).ready(function(){...` this just ensures that all elements on the page are fully loaded before trying to execute code. Otherwise you can get errors depending on where your script is located in the HTML

Comment: Thank you very much! Gonna have a look at this solution and try to embed it :-)

Comment: Shouldn't be too difficult! gl

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it using this plugin: https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview

```
var options = {
    useEasing : true, 
    useGrouping : true, 
    separator : ',', 
    decimal : '.', 
    prefix : '', 
    suffix : '' 
    };
    var c1 = new CountUp("a1", 0, 1000, 0, 5, options);
    var c2 = new CountUp("a2", 0, 1000, 0, 5, options);
    var c3 = new CountUp("a3", 0, 1000, 0, 5, options);
    var c4 = new CountUp("a4", 0, 1000, 0, 5, options);
    var c5 = new CountUp("a5", 0, 1000, 0, 5, options);
    var c6 = new CountUp("a6", 0, 1000, 0, 5, options);

    $('#counters').one('inview', function(event, isInView) {

    c1.start();
    c2.start();
    c3.start();
    c4.start();
    c5.start();
    c6.start();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code to run a function when element start getting into the view port.

---

You can see the code in action by clicking [jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uosahmed/frLoxm34/9/)

```
var counterTeaserL = $('.go-counterTeaser');
var winHeight = $(window).height();
if (counterTeaserL.length) {
    var firEvent = false,
        objectPosTop = $('.go-counterTeaser').offset().top;

        //when element shows at bottom
        var elementViewInBottom = objectPosTop - winHeight;
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        var currentPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
        //when element position starting in viewport
      if (currentPosition > elementViewInBottom && firEvent === false) {
        firEvent = true;
        animationCounter();
      }   
    });
}

//counter function will animate by using external js also add seprator "."
 function animationCounter(){
        $('.numberBlock h2').each(function () {
            var comma_separator_number_step =           $.animateNumber.numberStepFactories.separator('.');
            var counterValv = $(this).text();
            $(this).animateNumber(
                {
                  number: counterValv,
                  numberStep: comma_separator_number_step
                }
            );
        });
    }


https://jsfiddle.net/uosahmed/frLoxm34/9/
```

Comment: I think this is better than the accepted answer as it doesn't "do-something" every time you scroll