# JQuery How to animate milestone counter every time when in display

Tags: jquery, html

As the title says, basically how do I repeat the counter animation every time it is in display.

So far, I manage to make the milestone number animate and I found the code to do something when the target element is in view port.

But, I've no idea how to make both of them works. I tried to paste the animation code onto the //do something part, but it won't works.

Here's my progress so far

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
$('.count').each(function () {
    $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 4000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now).toLocaleString());
        }
    });
});
});

jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
(function($) {
    var $animation_elements = $('.count'),
        $window = $(window);
 
    function check_if_in_view() {
        var window_height = $window.height(),
            window_top_position = $window.scrollTop(),
            window_bottom_position = (window_top_position + window_height);
 
        $animation_elements.each(function() {
            var $element = $(this),
                element_height = $element.outerHeight(),
                element_top_position = $element.offset().top,
                element_bottom_position = (element_top_position + element_height);
 
            //check to see if this element is within viewport
            if ((element_bottom_position >= window_top_position) && (element_top_position <= window_bottom_position)) {
                $element.addClass('et-animated'); //test with adding new class is working
            } else {
                $element.removeClass('et-animated'); //test with removing the class is working
            }
        });
    }
 
    $window.on('scroll resize', check_if_in_view);
})(jQuery);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="margin-bottom: 500px;">Scroll down to see the counter</div>

<div><span class="count">123000</span></div>
<div><span class="count">3500000</span></div>
<div><span class="count">50000</span></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below acts as you have requested.

It checks if the `.count` elements are visible on page load and also after scrolling. It uses the class `.nonVisible` to help determine if the counter has just come into view or left it, this way we can stop animations appropriately.

If you do not stop the animation when the element scrolls out of view, then the animation will continue to run and if the element comes back into view it will not start again, but continue on the original animation.

Similarly, setting the text of the counter to '0' after it moves out of view means the user does not briefly see the previous figure before the counter restarts.

The code below is fully commented.

---

## Demo

```js
// Add event on document ready
$(document).ready(function() {



  // Add event on document scroll
  $(window).scroll(function() {

    // Cycle through each counter
    $(".count").each(function() {

      // Check if counter is visible
      if ($(this).isOnScreen()) {

        // Start counter
        startCounter($(this));

      } else {

        // Check if it has only just become non-visible
        if ($(this).hasClass("notVisible") == false) {

          // Stop animation
          $(this).stop();

          // Add nonVisible class
          $(this).addClass("notVisible");
          
          // This stops the user very briefly seeing the previous number before the counter restarts
          $(this).text("0");

        }

      }
    });
  });
});


// Check if an element is on screen
// Thanks to Adjit - taken from the url below
// Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23222131/jquery-fire-action-when-element-is-in-view#answer-23222523
$.fn.isOnScreen = function() {

  var win = $(window);

  var viewport = {
    top: win.scrollTop(),
    left: win.scrollLeft()
  };

  viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
  viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();

  var bounds = this.offset();
  bounds.right = bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
  bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();

  return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));


};


//Run counter, separate function so we can call it from multiple places
function startCounter(counterElement) {

  // Check if it has only just become visible on this scroll
  if (counterElement.hasClass("notVisible")) {

    // Remove notVisible class
    counterElement.removeClass("notVisible");

    // Run your counter animation
    counterElement.prop('Counter', 0).animate({
      Counter: counterElement.attr("counter-lim")
    }, {
      duration: 4000,
      easing: 'swing',
      step: function(now) {
        counterElement.text(Math.ceil(now).toLocaleString());
      }
    });
  }
}


// On page load check if counter is visible
$('.count').each(function() {

  // Add notVisible class to all counters
  // It is removed within startCounter()
  $(this).addClass("notVisible");

  // Check if element is visible on page load
  if ($(this).isOnScreen() === true) {

    // If visible, start counter
    startCounter($(this));

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div><span class="count" counter-lim="123000"></span></div>

<div style="margin-bottom: 500px;">Scroll down to see the counter</div>

<div><span class="count" counter-lim="123000"></span></div>
<div><span class="count" counter-lim="350000"></span></div>
<div><span class="count" counter-lim="50000"></span></div>
```

Comment: How do we make it only run once on a given page load? To where it doesn't keep counting up everytime it's in the viewport?